# Is there a way to make blender use slerp interpolation when keyframing a rotation using quaternion?

Tags: animation, transforms, interpolation, quaternion

I'm trying to get constant interpolation between keyframes when I rotate a bone or object using quaternion.

I already tried linear interpolation mode, however it still does not automatically give perfectly linear interpolation - if I wanted to get it to be perfectly linear, I'd have to do some crazy curve sin, cosine stuff that I don’t understand. My understanding is that with quaternion, this is called slerp and that blender doesn't do it by default. I don't know how right I am, and don't know how to code either.

Comment: SLERP is _Spherical Linear Ineterpolation_ and I believe it produces an _ease in/out_ effect.